# Find number or second largest number

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can i find second largest number in case i dont find the number i've searched?
for example
i am searching 3000 and on my db the largest number i've got is 2900 how can i find the second largest?

PHP Code:

```
$query = $select->from('numbers', array(
    'id'))
    ->where('number=?',$big_number);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `<=` instead of `=`

```
$query = $select->from('numbers', array(
    'id'))
    ->where('number<=?',$big_number)
    ->order('number DESC')
    ->limit(0, 1);
```

`Order` the resultset descending by the number, then `limit` the resultset to 1 row......

Answer (score 0):

What database are you talking about specifically?

Assuming you're talking about an SQL-based one or something similar, just fetch and order your data by the `number` column. Then use `LIMIT` to get the second result.